# Does the min/max notation relationship matche what i am trying to get?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

is this the right way to represent this relationship which is described in text on the picture? this is in min/max notation

http://s7.postimg.org/holux2uwb/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge lack of context here. I'll just kick a answer blindly.

In many cases while modeling data an order is usually seen as an event. I do not know exactly what is a "Bugel Card", but if it is a name of an identity such as a noun, and it has properties/attributes that must be stored, as I suspect it is the Customer, then we have two entities that have a relationship: the Customer entity, and the Bugel Card entity. The resulting connection/relationship/link forms the Order event.

If in an Order a Customer ALWAYS uses AT LEAST 1 "Bugel Card", and not more than that, then we have a cardinality (following the notation min max) of (1,1) between Customer and Bugel Card Entities, in both sides. For relationships (1,1) it takes the data modeler's discretion on which side will be set the relationship between the entities, that is, where the foreign key will go (once you decompose the Conceptual Model). It is always recommended to leave the foreign key on the side where in the future the relationship can become "many".

---

If you can improve a little more the context here, I can give you an answer with more accuracy (more correct), and remember:

**Do not model data without a full context.** When you go to an Entity Relationship Diagram starting from the Conceptual Model, you need a context, and one that is very well described. Without a full context, there is no diagram, and as a result, there is no database schema (or much less a system to use and manage).

Other than that, it is not possible to model entities without properties / attributes. Without them, an entity is nothing, because in its decomposition there will be no column to be created, and soon there will be no data to be persisted. Even if in your modeling process you let to define the attributes later you can end up confusing yourself and/or forgetting something. This is something prone to errors.

To be honest, there is no standard way of modeling data. What I have spoken so far are just data modeling tips. It is up to you what you want to do, and how you want to do.

Any questions, or anything else you need, please comment and I help you.